# how to judge the require.js end of the load all modules in global scope

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

how to know require.js loaded all modules in global scope?
eg:

```
<html>
    ...
<script src="require.min.js" data-main="main.js"></script>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(loaded) { //if loaded all modules call a function in some modules
            window.reqapi.getModule('test');
        }
    </script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
window.reqapi.getModule('test');
```

to a structure like this:

```
require([ 
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function 
    '{{your module}}'
], 
function(reqapi){ 
    reqapi.getModule('test');
});
```